# How can my user control get information from my aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ascx

I have a user control and inside the user control, the code is trying to set up a pop up window and set a label value by

```
document.getElementById("ReportTitle").innerText = TitleText;
```

The id "ReportTitle" is defined in the aspx page as

```
<a id="ReportTitle" style="font-family:Verdana; font-weight.bold; font-size:9px; cursor:pointer">Ocean Cargo</a>
```

It's also trying to set up the URL and a visibility property the same way. I am receiving the error "Unable to set property 'innerText' of undefined or null reference.' My first thought is that it is trying to set the value before the first window has finished loading and I've tried using window.open on the function containing the call to getElementById but it didn't work. I'm trying to determine if that is the issue or if it is unable to obtain "ReportTitle" because it's on the aspx page.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got it working. I had to change

`window.onload`

to

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        InitSearch();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if someone could tell me why my answer was down voted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with jQuery.

```
<a id="ReportTitle">Ocean Cargo</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var link = $("#ReportTitle");
    link.text("New Text");
    link.attr("href", "http://www.google.nl");
    //link.attr("style", "display:none");
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've only started researching jQuery so I have some more questions.                                                                                                        1)Does the <script> portion go in the aspx file where the element is defined?                                                                                                          2) I downloaded jquery.min.js and added it to my script folder. I added the src to the <head> tag in the aspx file. Do I need to put anything else?

Comment: That depens on your needs, but usually the scripts are kept in a separate file, `myScripts.js` for example that is placed in the `<head>` of the page just like you did with `jquery.min.js`, underneath the jQuery reference.

Comment: I can figure out how to get this to work with jQuery like you have above. I finally got something working using 'window.onload=InitSearch;' The popup window will now appear and display the information but map that appeared in the background will no longer display and some of the other searches will no longer work. I believe the onload in the <body> in the aspx page is being overwritten by the window.onload in the .ascx page